# Python ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded when accessing requests.get(apiUrl).json()

Tags: python, json

I am working on a tiny script which loads JSON data from several different URLs. Most of the requests work well using **requests.get(apiUrl).json()** but one endpoint connection causes **ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded**. The thing is that I can view proper (?) JSON response in the web browser - Firefox recognizes it and show it using nice JSON formatting. I can also view the content using **requests.get(apiUrl).text** but I'd rather have it in JSON to quick process it using list of dicts.

Do I have to validate the response to check if it really is JSON? Do not know how to approach this issue..

[Response in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qy4R.png)

[Firefox Response Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qmfmj.png)

```
try:
    r = requests.get(apiUrl)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        try:
            json_data = r.json()
        except ValueError as value_exc:
            print("Request to {} failed: {}".format(apiUrl, value_exc))
            print("Returned raw content: {}".format(r.text.encode('utf8')))
            print("Headers: {}".format(r.headers))
```

The response I get is:

```
Returned raw content: ï»¿[{"Id":1003616882932,"Sum":547.0,"Average":547.0,"WeightedNumerator":547.0,"Weight":1.0,"Cumulative":547.0,"Incremental":547.0,"EffectiveDate":"2016-03-31T00:00:00","Year":"2016-01-01T00:00:00","Quarter":"2016-01-01T00:00:00","Month":"2016-03-01T00:00:00","IsTarget":false,"IndicatorID":75879,"AwardID":39421,"ReportingPeriodID":6793,"LocationID":null,"AdminDivisionID":152472,"Level0AdminDivisionID":152337,"Level1AdminDivisionID":152472,"Level2AdminDivisionID":null,"Level3AdminDivisionID":null,"Level4AdminDivisionID":null,"OrganizationID":28058,"AwardingOrganizationID":28054,"AttributeValues":[]},{"Id":1003616882947,"Sum":889.0,"Average":889.0,"WeightedNumerator":889.0,"Weight":1.0,"Cumulative":1436.0,"Incremental":889.0,"EffectiveDate":"2016-09-30T00:00:00","Year":"2016-01-01T00:00:00","Quarter":"2016-07-01T00:00:00","Month":"2016-09-01T00:00:00","IsTarget":false,"IndicatorID":75879,"AwardID":39421,"ReportingPeriodID":6795,"LocationID":null,"AdminDivisionID":152472,"Level0AdminDivisionID":152337,"Level1AdminDivisionID":152472,"Level2AdminDivisionID":null,"Level3AdminDivisionID":null,"Level4AdminDivisionID":null,"OrganizationID":28058,"AwardingOrganizationID":28054,"AttributeValues":[]}]
Headers: {'Content-Length': '374', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'api-supported-versions': '1.0', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5', 'Last-Modified': 'Sat, 20 Jan 2018 21:02:46 GMT', 'ETag': 'W/"P39Pye7qMMOZP1HLK121Qw=="', 'Cache-Control': 'must-revalidate, max-age=0, s-maxage=0, private', 'Date': 'Wed, 07 Mar 2018 14:30:27 GMT', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
```

Comment: Why on earth you are using urllib2 and requests while doing the same thing? And have you tried to view `.content` of your response?

Comment: Oh, I started to work on a template code provided by the API developers - response = urllib2.urlopen(apiUrl) - that's their part. I am testing different methods to grab the data and after few tests requests module seemed to be fine. Returned content starts with **ï»¿&&[{"Id":1003616882932,"Sum":547.0,"Average":547.0,..**

Answer (score 0):

Having an HTTP 200 response doesn't necessarily means that you have a valid JSON as a response.

As you are not sharing the response, it is impossible for me to see if this is a valid JSON. However, it is a good practice to always validate responses that you have from an external URL. 
You could do this in python with:

```
# Store response in a variable to avoid doing a remote call twice if it raises
response = requests.get(apiUrl)
try:
    data = response.json()
except ValueError as e:
    # do some logs
    data = response.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't to use `urllib2` if you are already using `requests` and establish the connection two times...

You can just test if everything is ok in the same request:

```
import requests

try:
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        try:
            json_data = r.json()
        except ValueError as value_exc:
            print("Request to {} failed: {}".format(url, value_exc))
            print("Returned raw content: {}".format(r.text))
            print("Headers: {}".format(r.headers))
```

Comment: Thanks! After introducing your suggestion I get responses as in edited question.